# What is the exact age of Snoke?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi

As per [starwars.wikia.com](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snoke), Snoke was born "prior to 19 BBY [and] died 34 ABY" but what is his exact age?

Comment: Unknown. It is not explicitly mentioned in the films, nor the novels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The year 19 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/19_BBY) is also known as 3258 LY according to the Lothal Calendar.
[The year 34 ABY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/34_ABY) is also known as 3311 LY according to the Lothal Calendar.

That would mean that Snoke is *at least* 53 years old (by Lothal Calendar).

Comment: Snoke was born *prior to* 19 BBY, and not actually within that year.

Comment: @Charles yes, but that's the only year mentioned

Comment: Then the question can't be properly answered. ..if anything, your response should say, *".. is **at least** 53 years old."*

Comment: @Charles fixed it